# Is there a way to start a MySQL server outside of the command line on Windows?

Tags: mysql

I am about to begin teaching a class on SQL to people with no programming experience. At the start of the class, I want to offer guidance on installing and using MySQL in the simplest way possible. I am using a Mac, but want to be able to help students with Windows computers as well. On Mac, to start the server I can simply go to System Preferences > MySQL > Start MySQL Server to start the server. Is there an equivalently similar way of doing things on Windows, or does it need to be done in the command line?

I have seen videos where people have gotten a server to run in MySQL Workbench just by clicking on a MySQL connection instance on the startup page, but I have not been able to do that unless I have already run the server from System Preferences first.

It has been difficult to figure this out without access to a Windows machine to try this on. So, is there a similar way of starting a MySQL server on Windows through some sort of system preferences GUI as can be done on Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter Services in type here to search box, open,scroll down to find mysql right click and left click start,

for the long explanation  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-start-service.html

Answer (score 1):

We can start from the service available with the windows. To start from the service we can follow bellow steps.

METHOD #1: Access the Installed Service

- Open up the Services icon in the Control Panel
- Scroll alphabetically to the MySQL service
- Right click the service
- Click Start Service